# Django changes is not reflecting on the browser

Tags: python, html, django

It's my second day of Django and everything seems to be going petty well. Though the installation process is a bit longer, I still find it friendly to get started with. I am currently learning how to pass data to static file from views.py. The problem I am having is that it is only showing the previous changes not the recent. I have hard-refresh but still not working. I don't know how to stop and rerun the server because I don't know how to combine both Ctr + BREAK.

Comment: "I don't know how to combine both Ctr + BREAK." You can stop the dev server by pressing ctrl+c in the terminal too.

Comment: Thank you. But do I have to stop and rerun the server everytime I mage changes.  Is there something I can do once and for all instead of breaking and rerun the server everytime I made changes?

Comment: may be cache issue

Comment: If you're using `python manage.py runserver`, it should reload automatically. Does it not show you "(some file changed), reloading" or similar?

Comment: Yes I am using python manage.py runserver. Though the index.html is working fine, each change I made in the HTML updates in real-time. My problem is that the data I'm passing from views.py to index.html is not updating, I have to break the server and rerun it every time, which I find really strenuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + break mean pressing ctrl and alphabet c key at same time it will break the server and if you want to rerun it run the command
python manage.py runserver

There may be issue that you won't Saving your work other then this try force reload CSS file by pressing ctrl+ f5 in browser tab in which Django project is running.It might be helpful.

Comment: I came across this issue and ctrl+f5 in VSCODE worked for me. thanks

Comment: That's great...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and ctrl+f5 in VSCODE terminal. Great